# Can't save various entities in cakephp 4.4

Tags: save, associations, cakephp-4.x

I have a belongsto association between StatesxDays and three tables: Users, Groups, Nets, when I do `$user = $this->StatesxDays->Users->newEntities($this->request->getData());` it doesn't put the StatesxDays entities, this is the code for addUser action:

```
    public function addUser() {
        $this->loadModel('SourcingEvents');
        $statesxDay = $this->StatesxDays->newEmptyEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $guardar = false;
            $user = $this->StatesxDays->Users->newEntities($this->request->getData());
            debug($user);
            foreach($user->statesx_days as $data){
                $guardar = $this->StatesxDays->save($data);
            }
            if($guardar){
                $this->Flash->success(__('Se modificaron los estados de los usuarios.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('No se pudieron modificar los estados de los usuarios'));
        }
        $users = $this->StatesxDays->Users->find('all')->leftJoinWith('Groups')->where(['GroupsUsers.net_id' => $this->controllerUser['net_id']])
            ->contain(['Groups' => ['Nets'], 'Profiles']);
        $sourcingEvents = $this->SourcingEvents->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('statesxDay', 'users', 'sourcingEvents'));
    }
```

This is the code for add_user view:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \App\View\AppView $this
 * @var iterable<\App\Model\Entity\statesx_days> $statesx_days
 */
?>
<div class="statesx_days add_user content">
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->create($statesxDay);
        echo $this->Form->control('estado',['label'=>'Estado','options'=>[1 => 'Alerta verde', 2 => 'Alerta amarillo', 3 => 'Alerta naranja', 4 => 'Alerta rojo'], 'id' => 'estadoId']);
        //echo '<div id="selectEVent" style="display:none;">'.$this->Form->control('sourcing_event_id',['label'=>'Tipo de evento','options'=>$sourcingEvents,'empty'=>'-- Seleccionar evento --']).'</div>';
        echo $this->Form->button('Quitar selección',['type' => 'button', 'id' => 'quitar', 'class' => 'button float-right']);
        echo $this->Form->button('Seleccionar todos',['type' => 'button', 'id' => 'seleccionar', 'class' => 'button float-right']);
    ?>
    <h3><?= __('Cambiar estado de recursos humanos') ?></h3>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
            <th>Nivel</th>
            <th>Foto</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th>Rol</th>
            <th>Celula</th>
            <th>UF</th>
            <th>Nodo</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Aislado</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    <tbody>
        <?php
            $j = 0;
            foreach ($users as $user):
                $color = '';
                switch ($user->profile_id) {
                    case '2':
                        $color = '#000000';
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        $color = '#041d54';
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        $color = '#540404';
                        break;
                    case '5':
                        $color = '#6D147A';
                        break;
                    case '6':
                        $color = '#CC7400';
                        break;
                    case '7':
                        $color = '#2E2EBF';
                        break;            
                    default:
                        $color = '#30773D';
                        break;
                    }
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                            echo $user->profile_id;
                            $group = '';
                            $net = '';
                            $main_gate = '';
                            if($user->profile_id >= 3):
                                $group = $user->groups[0]->group_name;
                                if(!empty($user->groups[0]->_joinData->net_id)){
                                    $i = $user->groups[0]->_joinData->net_id - 1;
                                    $net = $this->Html->link($user->groups[0]->nets[$i]->net_name, ['controller' => 'Nets', 'action' => 'view', $user->groups[0]->_joinData->net_id]);
                                }
                                $main_gate = $user->groups[0]->_joinData->main_gate;
                                echo $this->Form->hidden('statesx_days.'.$j.'.group_id',['value'=>$user->groups[0]->id]);
                                echo $this->Form->hidden('statesx_days.'.$j.'.net_id',['value'=>$user->groups[0]->_joinData->net_id]);
                                echo $this->Form->hidden('statesx_days.'.$j.'.main_gate',['value'=>$main_gate]);
                            endif
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><?= $this->Html->image($user->image_file_name_url, ['title' => $user->image_file_name_filename, 'class' => 'img-circle']) ?></td>
                    <td><?= $user->email ?></td>
                    <td><?= $user->firstname ?></td> 
                    <td><?= $user->lastname ?></td> 
                    <td style="background-color:<?= $color ?>;color:#fff"><?= $user->profile->name ?></td> 
                    <td><?= $group ?></td> 
                    <td><?= $net ?></td> 
                    <td><?= (!empty($main_gate)) ? '#'.$main_gate : ' - ' ?></td> 
                    <td>
                        <?= $this->Form->control('statesx_days.'.$j.'.status',['label'=>false, 'options'=>[1 => 'Alerta verde', 2 => 'Alerta amarillo', 3 => 'Alerta naranja', 4 => 'Alerta rojo'], 'class'=>'status']) ?>
                        <?= $this->Form->hidden('statesx_days.'.$j.'.date',['value'=>date('Y-m-d')]) ?>
                        <?= $this->Form->hidden('statesx_days.'.$j.'.hour',['value'=>date('H:i:s')]) ?>
                        <?= $this->Form->hidden('statesx_days.'.$j.'.user_id',['value'=>$user->id]) ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?= $this->Form->checkbox($j.'.users.isolated',['value'=>true,'hiddenField' => false, 'class' => 'isolated']) ?>
                        <?= $this->Form->hidden($j.'.users.id',['value'=>$user->id]) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                        $j++;
                    endforeach;
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Guardar')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#estadoId').change(function(){
        status = $(this).val();
        $('.status').val(status);
        if(status=="1" || status=="3") $('#selectEVent').show();
        else $('#selectEVent').hide();
    })
})
$(function(){
    $('#seleccionar').click(function() {
        $('.isolated').prop('checked', true);
    });
});
$(function(){
    $('#quitar').click(function() {
        $('.isolated').prop('checked', false);
    });
});
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('.input_oculto').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

And this is what it shows debug($user):

```
APP/Controller/StatesxDaysController.php (line 54)
[
  (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) id:0 {
    '[new]' => true
    '[accessible]' => [
      'username' => true,
      'password' => true,
      'email' => true,
      'firstname' => true,
      'lastname' => true,
      'created' => true,
      'modified' => true,
      'profile_id' => true,
      'referrer_id' => true,
      'active' => true,
      'image_file_name_url' => true,
      'image_file_name' => true,
      'image_file_name_filename' => true,
      'map_lat' => true,
      'map_long' => true,
      'code' => true,
      'status' => true,
      'isolated' => true,
      'token' => true,
      'aro' => true,
      'profile' => true,
      'referrer' => true,
      'statesx_days' => true,
      'doctors' => true,
      'events_users' => true,
      'observations' => true,
      'pacients' => true,
      'status_groups' => true,
      'stocks_users' => true,
      'turns' => true,
      'doctorT' => true,
      'groups' => true,
    ]
    '[dirty]' => [
    ]
    '[original]' => [
    ]
    '[virtual]' => [
    ]
    '[hasErrors]' => false
    '[errors]' => [
    ]
    '[invalid]' => [
    ]
    '[repository]' => 'Users'
  },
  (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) id:1 {
    '[new]' => true
    '[accessible]' => [
      'username' => true,
      'password' => true,
      'email' => true,
      'firstname' => true,
      'lastname' => true,
      'created' => true,
      'modified' => true,
      'profile_id' => true,
      'referrer_id' => true,
      'active' => true,
      'image_file_name_url' => true,
      'image_file_name' => true,
      'image_file_name_filename' => true,
      'map_lat' => true,
      'map_long' => true,
      'code' => true,
      'status' => true,
      'isolated' => true,
      'token' => true,
      'aro' => true,
      'profile' => true,
      'referrer' => true,
      'statesx_days' => true,
      'doctors' => true,
      'events_users' => true,
      'observations' => true,
      'pacients' => true,
      'status_groups' => true,
      'stocks_users' => true,
      'turns' => true,
      'doctorT' => true,
      'groups' => true,
    ]
    '[dirty]' => [
    ]
    '[original]' => [
    ]
    '[virtual]' => [
    ]
    '[hasErrors]' => false
    '[errors]' => [
    ]
    '[invalid]' => [
    ]
    '[repository]' => 'Users'
  },
  (int) 2 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) id:2 {
    '[new]' => true
    '[accessible]' => [
      'username' => true,
      'password' => true,
      'email' => true,
      'firstname' => true,
      'lastname' => true,
      'created' => true,
      'modified' => true,
      'profile_id' => true,
      'referrer_id' => true,
      'active' => true,
      'image_file_name_url' => true,
      'image_file_name' => true,
      'image_file_name_filename' => true,
      'map_lat' => true,
      'map_long' => true,
      'code' => true,
      'status' => true,
      'isolated' => true,
      'token' => true,
      'aro' => true,
      'profile' => true,
      'referrer' => true,
      'statesx_days' => true,
      'doctors' => true,
      'events_users' => true,
      'observations' => true,
      'pacients' => true,
      'status_groups' => true,
      'stocks_users' => true,
      'turns' => true,
      'doctorT' => true,
      'groups' => true,
    ]
    '[dirty]' => [
    ]
    '[original]' => [
    ]
    '[virtual]' => [
    ]
    '[hasErrors]' => false
    '[errors]' => [
    ]
    '[invalid]' => [
    ]
    '[repository]' => 'Users'
  },
  (int) 3 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) id:3 {
    '[new]' => true
    '[accessible]' => [
      'username' => true,
      'password' => true,
      'email' => true,
      'firstname' => true,
      'lastname' => true,
      'created' => true,
      'modified' => true,
      'profile_id' => true,
      'referrer_id' => true,
      'active' => true,
      'image_file_name_url' => true,
      'image_file_name' => true,
      'image_file_name_filename' => true,
      'map_lat' => true,
      'map_long' => true,
      'code' => true,
      'status' => true,
      'isolated' => true,
      'token' => true,
      'aro' => true,
      'profile' => true,
      'referrer' => true,
      'statesx_days' => true,
      'doctors' => true,
      'events_users' => true,
      'observations' => true,
      'pacients' => true,
      'status_groups' => true,
      'stocks_users' => true,
      'turns' => true,
      'doctorT' => true,
      'groups' => true,
    ]
    '[dirty]' => [
    ]
    '[original]' => [
    ]
    '[virtual]' => [
    ]
    '[hasErrors]' => false
    '[errors]' => [
    ]
    '[invalid]' => [
    ]
    '[repository]' => 'Users'
  },
  (int) 4 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) id:4 {
    '[new]' => true
    '[accessible]' => [
      'username' => true,
      'password' => true,
      'email' => true,
      'firstname' => true,
      'lastname' => true,
      'created' => true,
      'modified' => true,
      'profile_id' => true,
      'referrer_id' => true,
      'active' => true,
      'image_file_name_url' => true,
      'image_file_name' => true,
      'image_file_name_filename' => true,
      'map_lat' => true,
      'map_long' => true,
      'code' => true,
      'status' => true,
      'isolated' => true,
      'token' => true,
      'aro' => true,
      'profile' => true,
      'referrer' => true,
      'statesx_days' => true,
      'doctors' => true,
      'events_users' => true,
      'observations' => true,
      'pacients' => true,
      'status_groups' => true,
      'stocks_users' => true,
      'turns' => true,
      'doctorT' => true,
      'groups' => true,
    ]
    '[dirty]' => [
    ]
    '[original]' => [
    ]
    '[virtual]' => [
    ]
    '[hasErrors]' => false
    '[errors]' => [
    ]
    '[invalid]' => [
    ]
    '[repository]' => 'Users'
  },
  (int) 5 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) id:5 {
    '[new]' => true
    '[accessible]' => [
      'username' => true,
      'password' => true,
      'email' => true,
      'firstname' => true,
      'lastname' => true,
      'created' => true,
      'modified' => true,
      'profile_id' => true,
      'referrer_id' => true,
      'active' => true,
      'image_file_name_url' => true,
      'image_file_name' => true,
      'image_file_name_filename' => true,
      'map_lat' => true,
      'map_long' => true,
      'code' => true,
      'status' => true,
      'isolated' => true,
      'token' => true,
      'aro' => true,
      'profile' => true,
      'referrer' => true,
      'statesx_days' => true,
      'doctors' => true,
      'events_users' => true,
      'observations' => true,
      'pacients' => true,
      'status_groups' => true,
      'stocks_users' => true,
      'turns' => true,
      'doctorT' => true,
      'groups' => true,
    ]
    '[dirty]' => [
    ]
    '[original]' => [
    ]
    '[virtual]' => [
    ]
    '[hasErrors]' => false
    '[errors]' => [
    ]
    '[invalid]' => [
    ]
    '[repository]' => 'Users'
  },
  (int) 6 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) id:6 {
    '[new]' => true
    '[accessible]' => [
      'username' => true,
      'password' => true,
      'email' => true,
      'firstname' => true,
      'lastname' => true,
      'created' => true,
      'modified' => true,
      'profile_id' => true,
      'referrer_id' => true,
      'active' => true,
      'image_file_name_url' => true,
      'image_file_name' => true,
      'image_file_name_filename' => true,
      'map_lat' => true,
      'map_long' => true,
      'code' => true,
      'status' => true,
      'isolated' => true,
      'token' => true,
      'aro' => true,
      'profile' => true,
      'referrer' => true,
      'statesx_days' => true,
      'doctors' => true,
      'events_users' => true,
      'observations' => true,
      'pacients' => true,
      'status_groups' => true,
      'stocks_users' => true,
      'turns' => true,
      'doctorT' => true,
      'groups' => true,
    ]
    '[dirty]' => [
    ]
    '[original]' => [
    ]
    '[virtual]' => [
    ]
    '[hasErrors]' => false
    '[errors]' => [
    ]
    '[invalid]' => [
    ]
    '[repository]' => 'Users'
  },
  (int) 7 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) id:7 {
    '[new]' => true
    '[accessible]' => [
      'username' => true,
      'password' => true,
      'email' => true,
      'firstname' => true,
      'lastname' => true,
      'created' => true,
      'modified' => true,
      'profile_id' => true,
      'referrer_id' => true,
      'active' => true,
      'image_file_name_url' => true,
      'image_file_name' => true,
      'image_file_name_filename' => true,
      'map_lat' => true,
      'map_long' => true,
      'code' => true,
      'status' => true,
      'isolated' => true,
      'token' => true,
      'aro' => true,
      'profile' => true,
      'referrer' => true,
      'statesx_days' => true,
      'doctors' => true,
      'events_users' => true,
      'observations' => true,
      'pacients' => true,
      'status_groups' => true,
      'stocks_users' => true,
      'turns' => true,
      'doctorT' => true,
      'groups' => true,
    ]
    '[dirty]' => [
    ]
    '[original]' => [
    ]
    '[virtual]' => [
    ]
    '[hasErrors]' => false
    '[errors]' => [
    ]
    '[invalid]' => [
    ]
    '[repository]' => 'Users'
  },
]
```

Let me clarify that I want to save various records to StatesxDays table and to modify two fields of various records of Users table, for that reason I use newEntities and not newEntity.

I want to save various records in StatesxDays table and modify various existing Users, not add new records to Users.